# What is the keyboard shortcut that opens the notifications and date dropdown on GNOME?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, notification-area

I am using GNOME on Ubuntu and I need to open the dropdown from the top. I was searching for a keyboard shortcut to open the dropdown as shown in the pictures below.

Normal screen:

[image: Normal screen]

Dropdown of notifications and date:

[image: Dropdown of notification and date]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dropdown is called [notification list](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-notifications.html.en).

You can open it by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

You can close it by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> again or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.